# Terraform - inverting a map

Tags: terraform

I'm stuck trying to write a terraform expression which can turn this:

```
subnets = {
   my_subnet_1 = {
     nsg       = "my_nsg_1",
     addresses = "my_addresses_1"
   }
   my_subnet_2 = {
     nsg       = "my_nsg_2",
     addresses = "my_addresses_2"
   }
}
```

into

```
nsgs_assocs = {
  my_nsg_1 = "my_subnet_1"
  my_nsg_2 = "my_subnet_2"
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
locals {
  nsgs_assocs = zipmap(
    var.subnets.*.nsg,
    keys(var.subnets)
  )
}
```

but this gives an error:

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on ..\..\modules\vnet\main.tf line 22, in locals:
  21:   nsgs_assocs = zipmap(
  22:     var.subnets.*.nsg,
  23:     keys(var.subnets)
  24:   )

Invalid value for "keys" parameter: element 0: string required.
```

For context, I've inherited a bunch of scripts which I'm trying to refactor without changing the results of a `terraform plan`.

One of the modules has a lot of related lookup maps - e.g:

```
nsgs_assocs = {
  my_nsg_1 = "my_subnet_1"
  my_nsg_2 = "my_subnet_2"
}

subnet_addresses = {
  my_subnet_1 = "my_addresses_1"
  my_subnet_2 = "my_addresses_2"
}
```

which I've condensed into my first above sample which I think will be more maintainable in the long run.

However, for backward compatibility with the existing terraform state I need to generate the original `nsgs_assocs` inside my module so that a `for_each` continues to use the nsg name as the resource key instead of the subnet name (which causes a destroy / create pair due to the key change).

Comment: What would be the expected outcome?

Comment: @marcin - I’m trying to get my local ```nsg_assocs``` to be the same value as the original, but using the new ```subnets``` as a data source. I’ll update the question shortly to clarify...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. It does not work, because [splat expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/splat.html) works with arrays, and `var.subnets` is a map. In order to fix it, you need to convert it into array and it can be done by using [values terraform function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/values.html):

```
locals {
  nsgs_assocs = zipmap(
    values(var.subnets)[*].nsg,
    keys(var.subnets)
  )
}
```

Comment: Ah, my root problem is in the small-print of the "splat" documentation - "if a splat expression is applied to a value that is not a list or tuple then the value is automatically wrapped in a single-element list before processing". My ```var.subnets.*.nsg``` was actually doing ```[var.subnets].*.nsg```. Interestingly, this fails in the console with an error "This map does not have an element with the key "nsg"" but i get ```Invalid value for "keys" parameter: element 0: string required.``` in ```terraform plan``` (unless I'm misunderstanding the effect of the splat operation

Comment: And I only just found ```terraform console```, which would have saved me hours if I'd known about it before :-).

Answer (score 3):

If you have:

```
variable "subnets" {
    default = {
       my_subnet_1 = {
         nsg       = "my_nsg_1",
         addresses = "my_addresses_1"
       }
       my_subnet_2 = {
         nsg       = "my_nsg_2",
         addresses = "my_addresses_2"
       }
    }
}
```

then the following is incorrect

```
var.subnets.*.nsg
```

Thus, it should be `values(var.subnets).*.nsg`:

```
locals {
  nsgs_assocs = zipmap(
    values(var.subnets).*.nsg,
    keys(var.subnets)
  )
}
```

resulting in:

```
{
  "my_nsg_1" = "my_subnet_1"
  "my_nsg_2" = "my_subnet_2"
}
```

Comment: +1 for a working answer, but I've accepted @rkm's as it touches on *why* my original attempt was failing as well, which helped me get my head around what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to achieve this, and the `zipmap`-based solutions others have shared are fine answers too, but I also wanted to show an example using [`for` expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/for.html) because I (subjectively) tend to think this form is easiest to read and understand:

```
locals {
  nsgs_allocs = {
    for k, s in var.subnets : s.nsg => k
  }
}
```

As long as all of your subnets have unique `nsg` values, the above should produce the result you were looking for.

In situations where the new key *isn't* unique -- for example, if in your cases there could be multiple subnets with the same `nsg` value -- you can use the `for` expression's "grouping" mode, which would produce a map of lists of subnet values so that there can potentially be more than one value under each key:

```
locals {
  nsgs_allocs = {
    for k, s in var.subnets : s.nsg => k...
  }
}
```

```
nsgs_assocs = {
  my_nsg_1 = ["my_subnet_1"]
  my_nsg_2 = ["my_subnet_2"]
}
```

Comment: I’m pretty new-ish to terraform so the ```for k, v:``` when iterating over maps is useful to know. Not sure I’m that charmed by the ```...``` operator though. Coming from a C# / Linq background, a ```group``` function would have been less jarring, but at least I’ll know what it is if I find it in the wild now :-).